# NodeJS request-json setting header breaks

Tags: json, node.js

I'm using request-json, found on npm, to query my API server.  My server requires that an auth token be passed in the header, but using request-json's method of setting headers produces the following error:

```
Error: "name" and "value" are required for setHeader().
at ClientRequest.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:333:11)
at new ClientRequest (_http_client.js:101:14)
at Object.exports.request (http.js:49:10)
at Request.start (C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\FrescoWeb\node_modules\request-js
on\node_modules\request\request.js:904:30)
at Request.write (C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\FrescoWeb\node_modules\request-js
on\node_modules\request\request.js:1625:10)
at end (C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\FrescoWeb\node_modules\request-json\node_mo
dules\request\request.js:666:16)
at Immediate._onImmediate (C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\FrescoWeb\node_modules\r
equest-json\node_modules\request\request.js:690:7)
at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:358:17)
```

I'm setting the header and hitting the endpoint in the following code:

```
var api = requestJson.createClient(config.API_URL);
api.headers['authtoken'] = req.session.token;
api.post(
'/v1/outlet/update',
  params,
  function(error, response, body){
    if (error)
      return res.json({err: error}).end();
    if (!body)
      return res.json({err: 'ERR_MISSING_BODY'}).end();
    if (body.err)
      return res.json({err: body.err}).end();

    req.session.user.outlet = body.data;
    req.session.save(function(){
      res.json({}).end();
    });
  }
);
```

When I comment `api.headers['authtoken'] = req.session.token;` out, the call doesn't crash.  Is there something that I am doing wrong, or do I have to migrate to `request` for http requests?

Comment: Have you checked what datatype and value is stored in `req.session.token` ?

Comment: Oh my god you may have found the problem.  Totally forgot the token it at req.session.user.token.  I'll let you know!

Comment: Add and accept a response with the solution. Easier to see than comments.

Answer (score 0):

`req.session.token` should be `req.session.user.token`